# Two ListViews (different element height) scrolling and positioning

Tags: android, listview, scroll, position, height

I have two listviews with different element height, but they show the same data. A picture will explain everything well:

[image: smaller list element represents bigger list element]

The listview on the right is a scrollbar representation of listview on the left (list of red/gray/purple days, future days go up, past days go bottom, with endless scroll listeners to fill up the same List).

The First problem is the ability to scroll one list and smoothly scroll the other one (having `smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisibleItem)` is choppy because for a long time of scrolling, the first visible item is the same item). I need every small scroll to be visible in the ScrollbarList and visa versa.

The Second problem is upon creation, i have today's index in the list (lets say 50th from 100), `setSelection(50)` on left List is ok, since one element takes most of the screen, but I dont know how to select the scrollbarList so that the same element would be visible in the middle of the small circle Indicator, so far `setSelectionFromTop(50, screenHeight/2)` is working.

**EDIT:**

I have managed to position both lists correctly to the center with code

```
dayListView.setSelectionFromTop(getTodayIndex(), screenHeight / 4);
scrollbarListview.setSelectionFromTop(getTodayIndex(), screenHeight / 2 - itemView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
```

And both list elements are on center, when no ScrollListeners are attached (except the endless scroll listener, which does not interact with other listviews). So now the only big problem is how to scroll them both smoothly with good aspect ration, when scrolling only of them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot trial and error, I found the best way to make synchronised scrolling work, so I'll share the idea and can elaborate if needed.

The first approach was to count the scroll delta of any list and use `smoothScrollBy(delta / aspectRatio)` with aspect ratio (and I needed to count aspect ratio in every step, since my element height of the left list can be different). But this way makes lists go out of sync soon after scrolling, so it was discarded.

The second approach that is currently working is calculating the center of the listview, calculating the middle child (current child hitting the listview center) and current distance between listview center and middle child center `middleElement.getTop() + middleElement.getHeight() /2;`. Then i use `middlePoistion = listView.getPositionForView(middleElement);`to get the position currently in the middle and move the list so the same element with middlePosition would be at the center of the screen but with offset of distance from element center to listview center : `otherListView.setSelectionFromTop(middlePoistion, otherListView.getHeight / 2 - otherListViewMiddleElement.getHeight() / 2 + distanceFromcenter);` and distance from center can be either negative or positive. If someone needs more explanation or code snippets, just ask.